# Linear Algebra Done Right 3.A.11, Confused by previous one

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[In this previous problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjap.png)I proved that this linear map T was not a linear map on V. I did this by:
$u \in U$ such that $Su \neq 0$ and let $v \in V\setminus U$. Then $T(u+v)=Tu+Tv=Su+0=Su$
But since $u+v$ is not in $U$.  $T(u+v) = 0$ which is a contradiction of $Su \neq 0$.

This makes perfect sense to me but if I continue to the next question 11
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj9IF.png)
This is what I have so far:

Let $u_1,...,u_m$ be a basis for $U$. You can then extend this basis to be a basis of $V$, which would be $u_1,...,u_m, v_{m+1},...v_n$. I then define $T \in L(V,W)$ such that $Tu=Su, \forall u \in U$.

I can then define this linear map to be $Su$ for $k = 1,...,m$ and $0$ for $k = m+1,..., n$. This is where i get confused. I just created the same piecewise definition that I proved in the previous question to not be a linear map on V.

Comment: The point is that now you are defining it to be zero on an arbitrarily chosen vector space complement of U. Which is good. Before you were defining it on the set theoretic complement, which is not a vector subspace. The one you defined now is not the same map as before: On any element $u_i + v_n$ the new one is not zero for example, although this element $u_i + v_n$ is not in $U$.

Comment: There is a solution for this book https://linearalgebras.com/3a.html

Comment: Oh, so since I defined the basis of V to be $w_1,...,w_m,v_{m+1},...,v_m$. So if I add lets say $w_1+v_m$ This will just give me some vector in the basis instead of giving me something that is V \ U?

Comment: I understand now... V \ U is not a vector space.